# Inequality with Fibonacci numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, fibonacci-numbers

The sequence $F_n$ of natural numbers defined by equation $F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_{n}$, with $F_0=0, F_1=1$ is called the Fibonacci sequence. The n-th term in the sequence is called the n-th Fibonacci number.

In many cases, the theory surrounding the Fibonacci numbers would often involve a special number $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{2}$ (golden ratio). For every integer $n\geq 1$ is simplest to prove that

$$
F_{n+1}<\phi^n
$$

Question: do you know of inequalities "closer" of the previous one? I.e., an inequalities

$$
F_{n+1}<f(n)
$$

such that

$$
F_{n+1}<f(n)<\phi^n
$$

Thank you very much.

Comment: Well there's a kind of silly derivation: $F_{n+1}=F_{n-1}+F_{n}<\phi^{n-2}+\phi^{n-1}=f(n)<\phi^n$ once you have proven your result by induction. And you can generalize this to get to lower powers of $\phi$. Are you looking for something more 'formulaic' or not as dependent on $\phi$?

Comment: Well, there is an **exact** expression for $F_n$ in terms of $\phi$ (see the Wikipedia article). That gives a *very sharp* inequality!

Comment: @AndréNicolas, What is it?

Comment: @Bryan, I am a curious person. I am looking for any formula! :-)

Comment: Andre has told you where to look.

Comment: [Here is the link.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio)

Comment: $F_n$ is the closest integer to ${\frac  {\varphi ^{n}}{{\sqrt  5}}}$
Therefore it can be found by rounding in terms of nearest integer function: $F_{n}={\bigg [}{\frac  {\varphi ^{n}}{{\sqrt  5}}}{\bigg ]},\ n\geq 0$ For $n$ even we have $F_n<\phi^n/\sqrt 5=f(n)$ but this is not true for n odd. Remember that I'm looking for an inequality of the type $F_n<f(n)$ and not $F_n>f(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha$ be the positive root of $x^2-x-1$, and $\beta$ be the negative root. Then $F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\alpha^n-\beta^n)$. This is called the Binet Formula.

If you want to prove this result, I suggest you can start first (by please proving) that $\alpha^{n}=\alpha F_n+F_{n-1}$, where $n \ge 1$. I won't give further hints.